# R: invalid multibyte string

Tags: r

I use read.delim(filename) without any parameters to read a tab delimited text file in R.

```
df = read.delim(file)
```

This worked as intended. Now I have a weird error message and I can't make any sense of it:

```
Error in type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, na.strings = character(0L)) : 
invalid multibyte string at '<fd>'
Calls: read.delim -> read.table -> type.convert
Execution halted
```

Can anybody explain what a multibyte string is? What does fd mean? Are there other ways to read a tab file in R? I have column headers and lines which do not have data for all columns.

Comment: check the file encoding (UTF8? Latin1?) and pass it to the read.delim function´s parameter fileEncoding

Comment: Tried that, no effect. I think the bug was in my Java program which put some weird characters in the text file. However, I would appreciate more comments on this because I'm not sure.

Comment: you could post the file and a reproducible example. then we could help out more.

Comment: Open your file in a text editor and use your eyeballs to find the weird characters, or serach for `<fd>`.  A multibyte-string is one which uses more than one byte to store each character (probably a Unicode string).

Comment: The strategy Richie suggest is sound, just make sure you use different editors. Some may show you the offending characters while others may not.

Comment: Usually that happen me when I received files from windows. Most of the cases they are solved with `read.table(file = "file.txt", fileEncoding = "latin1")`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I realize this is pretty late, but I had a similar problem and I figured I'd post what worked for me. I used the [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.1.html) utility (e.g., `"iconv file.pcl -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 -c"`). The "-c" option skips characters that can't be translated.

Comment: try setting the system localization with this code Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")

Comment: names(c) <- iconv(paste(children$id,children$name), from="UTF-8", to="UTF-8", sub="NA")

Answer (score 25):

If you want an R solution, here's a small convenience function I sometimes use to find where the offending (multiByte) character is lurking. Note that it is the *next* character to what gets printed. This works because `print` will work fine, but `substr` throws an error when multibyte characters are present.

```
find_offending_character <- function(x, maxStringLength=256){  
  print(x)
  for (c in 1:maxStringLength){
    offendingChar <- substr(x,c,c)
    #print(offendingChar) #uncomment if you want the indiv characters printed
    #the next character is the offending multibyte Character
  }    
}

string_vector <- c("test", "Se\x96ora", "works fine")

lapply(string_vector, find_offending_character)
```

I fix that character and run this again. Hope that helps someone who encounters the `invalid multibyte string` error.

Comment: Nice. This helped me find unknown/invisible characters in immensely huge R strings.

Answer (score 24):

I had a similarly strange problem with a file from the program e-prime (edat -> SPSS conversion), but then I discovered that there are many additional encodings you can use. this did the trick for me:

```
tbl <- read.delim("dir/file.txt", fileEncoding="UCS-2LE")
```

Comment: When using `readr` it would be `read_delim(someFile,  locale = locale(encoding = "windows-1252"))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out Leafpad to be an adequate and simple text-editor to view and save/convert in certain character sets - at least in the linux-world.

I used this to save the Latin-15 to UTF-8 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I had the 'copyright' symbol in one of my strings!  Once it was removed, problem solved.

A good rule of thumb, make sure that characters not appearing on your keyboard are removed if you are seeing this error.