# Error in tolower() invalid multibyte string

Tags: r

This is the error that I receive when I try to run `tolower()` on a character vector from a file that cannot be changed (at least, not manually - too large).

`Error in tolower(m) : invalid multibyte string X`

It seems to be French company names that are the problem with the `É` character. Although I have not investigated all of them (also not possible to do so manually).

It's strange, because my thought was that encoding issues would have been identified during `read.csv()`, rather than during operations after the fact.

Is there a quick way to remove these multibyte strings? Or, perhaps a way to identify and convert? Or even just ignore them entirely?

Comment: `tolower("École")` gives me `"école"` which seems right (I'm French :-))

Comment: This question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993837/r-invalid-multibyte-string

Comment: I should also mention that I don't get the same error on Windows (or at least, when I had Windows)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's how I solved my problem:

First, I opened the raw data in a texteditor (Geany, in this case), clicked properties and identified the Encoding type.

After which I used the `iconv()` function.

```
x <- iconv(x,"WINDOWS-1252","UTF-8")
```

To be more specific, I did this for every column of the `data.frame` from the imported CSV. Important to note that I set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in my `read.csv()` call.

```
dat[,sapply(dat,is.character)] <- sapply(
    dat[,sapply(dat,is.character)],
    iconv,"WINDOWS-1252","UTF-8")
```

Comment: An alternative for those, like me, too lazy to identify the encoding would be `x <- enc2utf8(x)`

Comment: Thanks man! this helped me a lot, I was banging my head here n there.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error. However, in my case it wasn't when I was reading the file, but a bit later when processing it. I realised that I was getting the error, because the file wasn't read with the correct encoding in the first place.

I found a much simpler solution (at least for my case) and wanted to share. I simply added encoding as below and it worked.

`read.csv(<path>, encoding = "UTF-8")`

Comment: Or "ISO-8859-1" or "Windows-1252". Great addition Onur!

Answer (score 5):

```
library(tidyverse)

data_clean = data %>%
    mutate(new_lowercase_col = tolower(enc2utf8(as.character(my_old_column))))
```

Where `new_lowercase_col` is the name of the new column I'm making out of the old uppercase one, which was called `my_old_column`.

Answer (score 4):

I know this has been answered already but thought I'd share my solution to this as I experienced the same thing.

In my case, I used the function `str_trim()` from package `stringr` to trim  whitespace from start and end of string.

`com$uppervar<-toupper(str_trim(com$var))`

Answer (score 0):

```
# to avoid datatables warning: error in tolower(x) invalid multibyte string
# assuming all columns are char
new_data <- as.data.frame(
  lapply(old_data, enc2utf8),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this issue

```
library(dplyr) # pipes
library(stringi) # for stri_enc_isutf8

#Read in csv data
old_data<- read.csv("non_utf_data.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")

#despite specifying utf -8, the below columns are not utf8:
all(stri_enc_isutf8(old_data$problem_column))

#The below code uses regular expressions to cleanse. May need to tinker with the last 
#portion that selects the grammar to retain

utf_eight_data<- old_data %>% 
  mutate(problem_column = gsub("[^[:alnum:][:blank:]?&/\\-]", "", old_data$problem_column)) %>%
rename(solved_problem = problem_column)

#this column is now utf 8.

all(stri_enc_isutf8(utf_eight_data$solved_problem))
```