# Invalid multibyte string 228 while reading rds file in r

Tags: html, r

```
data <- readRDS("path") ## reading the file from the location
names(data$)
```

while fetching any information getting below error:

> Error in tolower(completions) : invalid multibyte string 228

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in tolower() invalid multibyte string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187605/error-in-tolower-invalid-multibyte-string)

Comment: No. This issue which i am getting while reading rds file. Not csv file.

Comment: issue might be with encoding in your file, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876746/how-to-read-data-in-utf-8-format-in-r