# Shiny App from Posit Cloud Character Encoding Issue?

Tags: r, shiny, character-encoding, cloud

I have built a few apps in Shiny on my local console, but am trying to migrate to Posit Cloud for ease of use going forward. I installed Shiny and connected to my shiny apps account on Posit Cloud. However, it appears the file is not being read in totality to the app upon startup.

Specifically, I have a file that is 94.2 MB in the app folder that is to be read upon startup. I have never had an issue with this on local console, but I am assuming the full file is being cutoff on my read attempt in the app given that I am not seeing my full list of options from a dropdown menu that is part of the app. I am also seeing this error:

```
Warning: Error in tolower: invalid multibyte string 19279
```

Any suggestions on a workaround here? Or can I simply not use files this size when building apps from Posit Cloud?

***EDIT***
It appears this is an issue with the encoding and character "é"

I did a small hack and just removed this row from the dataframe since it was trivial to the result, but that is obviously not a long-term solution.

I tried some of the suggestions listed in these two posts:

[Error in tolower() invalid multibyte string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187605/error-in-tolower-invalid-multibyte-string)

[How to detect the right encoding for read.csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806823/how-to-detect-the-right-encoding-for-read-csv)

But I wasn't finding a solution. Perhaps I need to do more digging on the original encoding in the source file? I tried a few different changes and none of them worked.

**SECOND EDIT**

Runnings `Sys.locale()` on my console returns `English_United States.1252` while Posit Cloud returns `C.UTF-8`

I assume this is relevant, but honestly it is beyond the scope of my experience so far.

Currently I am converting to UTF8 in the app upon upload.

Comment: Look up locale and/or unicode conversion, the multibyte sequence sounds like `Sys.getlocale()` on your local machine is different than on the posit-cloud instance; perhaps add it to your script, redeploy, then see what is different. From there, you can come back here and edit your question to provide more context, including a sample of text that is causing the problem.

Comment: Having said that, googling for [`"R" tolower multibyte string`](https://www.google.com/search?q="R"+tolower+multibyte+string) for me includes https://stackoverflow.com/q/13187605/3358272, for which this question is likely a dupe. (The quoted "R" is very useful/important when web-searching for R-related pages.)

Comment: Appreciate it! I came up with a dummy solution, but nothing longterm @r2evans

Question edited.