# R: Frequency table that is case insensitive

Tags: r

Here is one column of my df: [df$City] 
(I have other columns, but I'm just showing one column for simplicity.)

```
City        
Seattle     
San Diego   
Bern       
SEATTLE
SEATTLE
BERN
```

I want to do a frequency count on the cities. I want both "Seattle" and "SEATTLE" to be considered the same - basically, I want the frequency table calculation to be case insensitive.

If I use `table(df)` it gives me "Seattle" and "SEATTLE" as two different items. I tried to overcome this by using `toupper(df)` before doing table(df)

However, I get the error: `invalid multibyte string.`

I checked the encoding of my file and it seems to be UTF-8 - I could be wrong - is there a way for me to check the encoding?

Does anyone know how I can get a frequency table that is case insensitive? It doesn't have to be using my approach.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `table(toupper(df$alpha))`.

Comment: @eipi10, thanks for the answer. However, this doesn't work. It gives me the error: "invalid multibyte string"

Comment: I just noticed that the column you posted is actually called `City`. What is `alpha`?

Comment: @eipi10, I apologize - it was a typo on my part. It should be City - I have changed it accordingly.

Comment: The answer by @eipi10 (with the correct column name) should work. If it doesn't, you should post `dput(head(df))` so we can see your real data.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to look into `iconv()` for the UTF-8 conversion. Also, with the strings, you will probably have to use `toupper()` or `tolower()` to standardize them, and maybe `stringr::str_trim()` to take care of extra white-space...

Comment: Worth mentioning [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993837/r-invalid-multibyte-string) post which goes into some reasons why the `invalid multibyte string` error could come up