# RStudio Server - load file.RData Error : invalid multibyte string

Tags: r, shiny, locale, rstudio, shiny-server

I have a file `file.RData` with one of the data frames containing values with Swedish characters.

When loading `file.RData` in the Shiny app, it works fine on the local Windows machine, but when I move it to Ubuntu server and run it in RStudio Server: I get `Error : invalid multibyte string`

I changed Ubuntu's locale to `sv_SE.UTF-8`, rebooted and I still get the error. I've been looking at other similar problems [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363085/invalid-multibyte-string-in-read-csv)  [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993837/r-invalid-multibyte-string) , but don't know how to adapt it to my particular situation.

Is there any way to make my Shiny app work on Shiny server and keep `file.RData` with Swedish characters?

Here's a sample of my code in `app.R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

(WD <- getwd())
if (!is.null(WD)) setwd(WD)

load ("file.RData")

server<-function(input,output){
.......
}

ui<-fluidPage(
.......
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to convert the columns of the data frames, which had Swedish characters, by adding the following code after loading the `file.RData`:

```
load ("file.RData")    

Encoding(df1$TEAM)<-"latin1"
Encoding(df2$TEAM)<-"latin1"
Encoding(df3$Team)<-"latin1"
```