# I can't seem to access the data in my file?

Tags: r

```r
library(tidyverse)
y <- read_tsv("assignment_data.tsv")
x <- 1
```

When I check R console I get the following:

```r
> y <- read_tsv("assignment_data.tsv", header=TRUE)
Error in read_tsv("assignment_data.tsv", header = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (header = TRUE)
> 
> x <- 1
>
```

However, I can only access x in the global environment and I can't visualize the data in the file I tried to import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your error:

```
Error in read_tsv("assignment_data.tsv", header = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (header = TRUE)
```

If you use

```
?read_tsv
```

you will find `header` is not one of the arguments. Instead, you are looking for `col_names`

Edit:
We found out the problem laid within the tsv itself. The number of column names did not match the number of columns (implied by data)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, but I still can't access the data?

Comment: np. When u say u can't access file. Could u let us know the error message?

Comment: I can't type 'y' in the console to open up the data in R

Comment: when u type `y` into console what error message did u get?

Comment: object not found

Comment: type `ls()` into console. Does `y` exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243123/discussion-between-sweepy-dodo-and-github292929).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71549730/object-not-found-despite-data-being-imported