# Error while using the function tbl_summary()

Tags: r, summary, tbl

I'm trying to use the function "tbl_summary()", but I'm having the problem below, could someone help me, please?

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `df_stats = pmap(...)`.
Caused by error in `manip_apply_syms()`:
! invalid multibyte string at ''

Thank you,
Lays.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will likely find colleagues willing to help, but only if there is more information.  Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to improve your question.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is, imho, not the tbl_summary() problem itself, but the bigger issue. The problem may be caused by some character(s) - probably Unicode - which can arise if the file is produced by software using different encoding system and then imported to R (however I can not be sure without the reprex).

Here is a similar thread: [R: invalid multibyte string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993837/r-invalid-multibyte-string)
for instance, you can use Ram Narasimhan's function to find offending character and remove/convert it. Alternatively you may open your file in the text editor and change encoding/delete whitespaces etc..

Answer (score 0):

you need to load
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
and that's it